# AWS ECR Login with podman

Tags: amazon-web-services, redhat, amazon-ecr, podman

Good morning/afternoon/night!
Can you help me, please?

I'm working with RHEL 8.2 and this version doesn't support Docker. I installled Podman and everything was ok until I use the following command:

```
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)
```

But, it doesn't work because it's from Docker (I thought it was from AWS Cli).

The error is:

```
# $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)
-bash: docker: command not found
```

I've been searching for an answer and some people used a command like this:

```
podman login -u AWS -p ....
```

But I tried some flags and the image, but nothing is working!

What is the equivalent command for podman?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The above command is not associated to docker alone.

It is an AWS cli command to authenticate into the private container image registry(ECR).

Run the below command to get the password for container registry

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | podman login --username AWS --password-stdin <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: The accepted answer cannot work because `podman --password-stdin ` means "read the password from stdin". This answer was copied incorrectly from https://github.com/vumdao/lambda-container-image#-build-and-push-the-image-to-ecr. The 2 commands should have been connected via a pipe

Comment: Yes! Today, I'm using like this:
`aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | podman login --username AWS --password-stdin <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Downvoted for presenting what was clearly intended to be a single command as two separate commands...

Comment: The token from `ecr get-login-password` is region-specific, so the AWS region for `aws ecr get-login-password ...` and the ECR URI must macht. I try to adpat the response above.

Answer (score 8):

This is how the password from `aws ecr` is piped to `podman` using [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/). BTW, the username `AWS` is hardwired and so never needs to be changed:

```sh
$ aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | \
  podman login \
    --username AWS \
    --password-stdin \
    <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

Podman will use the IAM credentials for the `dev` profile in `~/.aws/credentials` to log into that AWS account:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ********************
aws_secret_access_key = ****************************************
region = us-east-1

[dev]
aws_access_key_id = ********************
aws_secret_access_key = ****************************************
region = us-east-1
```

This is how real values can be looked up for profile `dev`:

```sh
$ export AWS_PROFILE=dev

$ AWS_ACCOUNT="$( aws sts get-caller-identity \
  --query Account \
  --output text
)"

$ AWS_REGION="$( aws configure get region )"

$ aws ecr get-login-password \
    --region $AWS_REGION | \
  podman login \
    --password-stdin \
    --username AWS \
    $AWS_ACCOUNT.dkr.ecr.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com
```

The above is from my [blog post](https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2021/04/29/buildah-podman-python-lambda.html) on the subject.